# Ecrire un quadrigramme

Tags: orthographe

Existe-t-il en français des règles particulières ou du moins des préconisations quant à l'abréviation de mots en quadrigrammes ?

Typiquement, si je voulais écrire un quadrigramme à partir du mot `quadrigramme`, devrais-je plutôt l'écrire `quad` ou `qdrg` ? 
Peut-être existe-t-il une norme ISO ou AFNOR pour adresser ce problème ?

Comment: Cette question est incompréhensible. À quel usage se destineraient de tels quadrigrammes ?

Comment: @qoba je vois pas en quoi l'usage que je compte en faire t'aiderait en quoi que ce soit mais si tu veux tout savoir c'est pour créer des normes de nommage de scripts.

Comment: Parce que sans contexte, la définition d'un quadrigramme est simplement un mot de quatre caractères. Vu le contexte je crois que ce que tu recherches est une règle d'abréviation de mots ?

Comment: @qoba oui. On peut dire ça ainsi. Tu as une réponse a proposer?

Comment: J'ai une idée de réponse mais pas le temps de l'écrire tout de suite. En attendant voici un pointeur sur les règles usuelles d'abréviations, qui ne s'appliquent pas exactement à ton cas mais qui peuvent t'orienter. http://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/monde/regles-5ABREVIATIONS.htm ... As-tu besoin de quatre lettres exactement ou bien au plus quatre lettres ?

Comment: C'est toujours difficile de répondre aux questions "existe-il" parce que même si on est quasiment sûr que ça existe pas, on sait jamais avec 100% de certitude. Mais je pense qu'il y a pas de normes ou de réglementations officielle, tu fais un peu comme tu veux. Je rejoins Qoba sur le conseil de garder des syllabes marquantes du mot (par ex. `qdgm`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les références que j'ai pu trouver sur la formation des abréviations ne traitent pas vraiment de la contrainte posée de tenir en quatre lettres ; néanmoins elles offrent des généralités :

- On peut former des abréviations à partir du début d'un mot, soit en conservant la première lettre seulement, soit en coupant après une consonne et avant une voyelle. Par exemple:

> Direction --> Dir.
>
> Nord --> N.

- On peut également former des abréviations à partir des lettres initiales et finales du mot. Par exemple :

> Vieux --> Vx
>
> Docteur --> Dr

- On peut aussi former des abréviations à partir de l'initiale, de la finale, et de quelques consonnes "marquantes" du mot :

> quelqu'un --> qqn
>
> boulevard --> bld, bvd, blvd
>
> traitement -> ttmt

En tout cas, certaines abréviations d'usage courant sont généralement à privilégier. Par exemple, si "Docteur" pourrait théoriquement s'abréger en "Dctr" selon l'une des précédentes formules, les abréviations "Dr" et "Doct." étant déjà bien établies seraient normalement à privilégier.

http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect1&info0=1

http://www.les-abreviations.com/procedes.html